# How can I change one variable in class every time when another changes? Python

Tags: python

Here is my code and I want the damage to change every time the level changes

```
class Item:
    __ids = count(0)

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Nothing'
        self.id = next(self.__ids)
        self.level = 1


class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.damage = 1

    def setDamage(self):
        self.damage = (self.level * 2.25, self.level * 2.25 + self.level // (self.level / 2))

    @property
    def damage(self):
        return self.damage

    @damage.setter
    def damage(self):
        self.setDamage()
```

*Ignore the incorrectness of the code if it does not interfere with the question, I am new in python*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no reason to set a weapon's damage at all; it is *entirely* a function of the weapon's level.

```
 #  Irrelevant code removed
 class Item:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 1

class Weapon(Item):    
    @property
    def damage(self):
        base = self.level * 2.25
        return (base, base + self.level // (self.level / 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this could do what you want. I'm not sure how you want the damage to scale with the level. I have it set to always be 2.25x whatever the level is.

```py
class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def damage(self):
        return self.level * 2.25
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a levelUp() function might be a better idea than changing the level externally at all.

```
def levelUp():

    self.level+=1
    self.setDamage()
    #any other level up stuff like a shinier picture
```

Currently to level something up you have to find its current level, which is tiresome, and find some way to automatically update the damage when level is changed, which would be an non-obvious side-effect of this assignment.

```
sword.level = sword.level + 1
```

With a `levelUp` function you can just do

```
sword.levelUp()
```

Without having to check its current state at all.  This also allows you to handle levelling up differently for each item type (what if there isn't a simple mathematical relationship between damage and level for some other weapon, or you want to limit it at some upper limit etc.)

You can always safely just do

```
for item in items:
    item.levelup()
```